# Resampling of time signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, resampling

I want to resample my signal with to new time. Currently the sampling time of my signal is `0.01s`, and the size of my signal and time array is `1*90001`.

I am trying to use `resample(x,p,q)` in MATLAB, but I am a little bit confused.

Can somebody suggest the right way to use this function and how to resample my data to rate of `0.02s` instead of `0.01s`?

**Code** - this is how I am trying to use `resample`, with example data.

```
t = [0:0.03:1];
x = sin(4*pi*t);
y = resample(x, 1, 2);
ty = resample(t,1,2);

figure (1);
stem(ty, y, 'r*');
hold on;
stem(t,x,'b')
hold off
```

**Updated Code :**

```
t = [0 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 31 32 33 35 37 41 ];
A = [0 0 1 2 3 5.2 0 -1.4 0 2 2.7 2 2.3 6 7.3 0 0 -8.6 0 1 1 2.5 3 4.8 2];
plot(t,A)
% Tx = min(diff(t));
Tx = 1:0.1:25;
B = interp1(t,A,Tx); %re-make example data to have decimal points on the x-axis
 y = resample(B, 2, 1); 
 T = 0.05;
 Ty = T / (2 / 1); 
 ty = (0:length(y)-1)*Ty;
% A = interp1(t,ref,t2);
% A = ref;
figure 
plot(Tx,B,'b')
hold on
plot(ty,y,'r')
plot(t,A,'g')
hold off
```

Answer (score 1):

your original signal is sampled with uniform sampling interval of 10 ms and you want to decrease sampling down to 20 ms. Why don't you just take every second datapoint of your original signal?

```
y = x(1:2:end);
ty = t(1:2:end);
```

**UPDATE**

for non regularly spaced datasets it is possible to use function `resample` as it is shown here: https://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html#bungoxs

you can try

```
fs = 1/0.02;
[y, ty] = resample(x, t, fs, 1, 2)
```

Comment: This is absolutely wrong because of aliasing: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: Sorry but in my case it will not work I have tried it as in my case both time and data sample array values are not uniformly sampled so this will not make sense in my case as it will cause wrong sampling of data signal for me . Sorry and thanks a lot for useful addition for others this is an easy way to down sample.

Comment: @john You state in the question that your original data is sampled every 10ms, that's uniform sampling by definition...

Comment: Sorry wolfie for this and thanks a lot for restructuring question in more sensible way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: fs = 1; [y] = resample(yg,fs,3,1); [ty] = resample(t,fs,3,1); plot(t,yg,'o',ty,y,'.-') xlabel('Day')

Comment: @Artyom I am using this logic now for example that you have provided but I am getting the result as shown in attached picture. Can you describe me please what’s the meaning of it what does fs plays a role here. Sorry for disturbance and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @john did you try this code? `fs = 1/0.02;
[y, ty] = resample(x, t, fs, 1, 2);`

Comment: Yes but unfortunaltely it needs MATLAB upgradation for me I am getting error for this that’s why I spllited it into two parts but I think it’s not a good idea what I have done .

Comment: yes, this is wrong. With these input arguments, the function does something entirely different. What Matlab version do you have?

Comment: Is there any alternative also for this

Comment: I would use what @AndreiDavydov proposed. resampling together with interpolation

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need to resample time line.
It is much easier to define time sampling interval variable or sampling frequency variable:  `T = 0.03; Fs = 1/T;`

So,  `x`  resampling you perform right way:  `y = resample(x, 1, 2);` .

But the new time line must be reconstructed via adjusted sampling interval:  `Ty = T / (1 / 2); ty = (0:length(y)-1)*Ty;`

The  `resample`  function is suitable only for uniformly time distributed data points. If your original points are non-uniformly distributed, you need:

1. Interpolate your  `x`  signal to the uniform time line with the smallest sampling interval from the original time line:  `Tx = min(diff(t));` . See for example  `interp1`  function.
2. Resample your interpolated uniformly time distributed (sampled) signal to the new sampling interval ( `resample`  function).

Comment: Andrei Davydov Thanks a lot just give me few minutes I will play around with it and get back to you but it seems a great logic and looks that it will work for me just few minutes needed to have a look at it deeply. Thanks a lot .

Comment: `resample` may be used for non-uniformly sampled signals as well. This example shows it: https://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html#bungoxs  Also resample provides new grid as an output argument (see the same link)

Comment: @john I updated my original wrong answer. Try to take a look at the advice I give there. Please comment there if you don't understand something

Comment: @Andrei Davydov please have a look at updated code I have made by using logic explained by you but one question will not this approach effect our original signal means we are adding extra points and again resampling those means original data will distort right please correct me if I am mistaken .

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to resample in a lower frequency your data.
Use this **code**:

```
fs=1/(timesignal(2)-timesignal(1)); %for example 48000Hz
fs_resampled=100; % [Hz] example goal value 
t_original = [0:1/fs:(1/fs*(length(signal)-1))];%current time signal
t_resampled = [0:1/fs_resampled:max(t_original)];%new time signal
Signal_resampled = interp1(t_original,signal,t_resampled,'spline');
```

I hope that's what you wanted.
Greetings