# Resampling of an audio signal with new time array

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am asking an upgraded and more focused version of my query as I think I remained unable to explain properly in my last query.

I want to `down sample` my signal based on new time array.

I have `time array` and `sample array`.

```
t = [0 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20];

A = [0 0 1 2 3 5.2 0 -1.4 0 2 2.7 2 2.3];
```

New time array is:

```
Tx = 1:4:25;
```

I am using interpolation proposed by Andrei Davydov on stackoverflow but I think I am at fault some point.

Can someone point me out where I am at fault? Thanks a lot in advance.

If the value of A is same at Tx as w.r.t (t)then use that value and if no value is found interpolate value and assign that value to new time .

Example Code:

```
t = [0 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20 ];
A = [0 0 1 2 3 5.2 0 -1.4 0 2 2.7 2 2.3 ];
plot(t,A)
Tx = 1:4:25;
B = interp1(t,A,Tx); %re-make example data to have decimal points on the x-axis
 y = resample(B, 1, 2); 
 T = 0.05;
 Ty = T / (1 / 2); 
 ty = (0:length(y)-1)*Ty;
figure 
plot(Tx,B,'b')
hold on
plot(ty,y,'r')
plot(t,A,'g')
hold off
```

Link to my previous question is attached here.

[Resampling of time signal in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789868/resampling-of-time-signal-in-matlab/47790101?noredirect=1#comment82545332_47790101)

**Note :**

This is now exactly what i want so this is more clear and mature.

I am using MATLAB version 2012b so please provide me solution w.r.t that as there are few Matlab build in command which don't work in 2012b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main Your problem - you try to extrapolate, as original time ends at 20, but Yours ends at 25. Try this code:

```
clc
t = [0 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20 ];
A = [0 0 1 2 3 5.2 0 -1.4 0 2 2.7 2 2.3 ];

Tx = 1:4:25; % Are you sure you want to extrapolate?
              % max(Tx1)>max(t)

% This variant is WITHOUT extrapolation
B = interp1(t,A,Tx);
% This variant is WITH extrapolation and WHOLE time-series interpolated
% cubically
extrapBcub=interp1(t,A,Tx,'pcchip');
% If you want to have linear (default) interpolation, but cubic
% extrapolation then
extrapBlin=[B(~isnan(B)), extrapBcub(isnan(B))];
```

It gives the following figure:

```
f=figure('Position',[50 50 1500 800])
h1=subplot(1,2,1);
hold all
h(1)=plot(t,A,'-ok','LineWidth',3)
h(2)=plot(Tx,B,'-ob','LineWidth',9)
h(3)=plot(Tx,extrapBcub,':or','LineWidth',7)
h(4)=plot(Tx,extrapBlin,'-og','LineWidth',3)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('signal')
set(gca,'Box','off','Color','none','FontSize',14,'LineWidth',2)
legend({'Original data','No extrapolation','Cubic all',...
    'Linear interpolation+cubic extrapolation'},'Location','SouthOutside',...
    'FontSize',22)
legend boxoff
h2=subplot(1,2,2);
hold all
h3 = copyobj(h(end:-1:1), h2) % copy plots just for scaling
ylim([-2 6])
xlabel('time')
ylabel('signal')
set(gca,'Box','off','Color','none','FontSize',14,'LineWidth',2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot zlon it worked well . Have a nice time.